# jenkins API token with LDAP authentication

Tags: authentication, curl, jenkins

We have `Jenkins` running with `Active Directory` authentocation and all good, Today when i tried `curl` to post files and it didn't work with `API token` but it does work with Password.

I got following ldap error.. Anybody has any experience? but it works with plain text password. because of security reason i don't want to use password

```
 curl -X POST http://spatel:d606d1857409cc8ef1f2dff8aaab1cf1@server1.example.com/job/Test/config.xml --data-binary "@config.xml"

    Jun 3, 2013 2:33:01 PM hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider retrieveUser
    WARNING: Failed to retrieve user information for spatel
    javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 00000000: LdapErr: DSID-0C090627, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, vece]; remaining name 'DC=example,DC=com'
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_search(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.plugins.active_directory.LDAPSearchBuilder.search(LDAPSearchBuilder.java:52)
        at hudson.plugins.active_directory.LDAPSearchBuilder.searchOne(LDAPSearchBuilder.java:42)
        at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:191)
        at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:130)
        at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:95)
        at hudson.plugins.active_directory.AbstractActiveDirectoryAuthenticationProvider.loadUserByUsername(AbstractActiveDirectoryAuthenticationProvider.java:27)
        at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.loadUserByUsername(ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.java:551)
        at hudson.model.User.impersonate(User.java:255)
        at jenkins.security.ApiTokenFilter.doFilter(ApiTokenFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm interested in it too!

Comment: after lots of googling i have found its BUG..